# ec2 can't http but can ping, ssh and ftp

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon Linux AMI instance running with an IPv4 Public IP and a Public DNS (IPv4).

I can SSH and FTP to the instance, but I can't HTTP to it.

If I add a Custom ICMP inbound rule, I can ping the IP.

Both HTTP/HTTPS are wide open.

Web requests to the IP in Chrome say "refused to connect."

What could I be missing? For example, is there a built in firewall?

Comment: Is your webserver listening on `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`. Does it listen on a non standard port (other than 80, 443)?

Comment: Why should it respond to HTTP requests? What makes you think that it is running a web server -- did you install one? If you did, then SSH into the instance and try `curl http://localhost` -- if the web server is working, an HTML response should appear. If it does not, then you are not running a web server.

Comment: Thanks John. I did not realize that I had to specifically install Apache, MySQL and PHP after installing the AMI.